# Let $\sum\frac{1}{a^3+1}=2$. Prove that $\sum\frac{1-a}{a^2-a+1}\ge 0$

Tags: inequality, fractions, holder-inequality, jensen-inequality, tangent-line-method

> Let $a,b,c$ are nonnegative real numbers such that $\frac1{a^3+1}+\frac1{b^3+1}+\frac1{c^3+1}+\frac1{d^3+1}=2$.
>
> Prove the inequality
> $$\frac{1-a}{a^2-a+1}+\frac{1-b}{b^2-b+1}+\frac{1-c}{c^2-c+1}+\frac{1-d}{d^2-d+1}\ge0$$

#### My attempts:

Let
$$A=\frac{1-a}{a^2-a+1}+\frac{1-b}{b^2-b+1}+\frac{1-c}{c^2-c+1}+\frac{1-d}{d^2-d+1}$$

If $a=1$ then $A=0$ then inequality is hold. If $a\not=1$ then

$$A=\frac{1-a^2}{a^3+1}+\frac{1-b^2}{b^3+1}+\frac{1-c^2}{c^3+1}+\frac{1-d^2}{d^3+1}$$

*I tried the method of Lagrange multipliers and Jensen's inequality but I have not been proved this inequality*

Comment: Why all these $2$ in the hypothesis?

Comment: Have you written this the way you intended?  Why not divide the assumed equation by $2$?

Comment: I copied it from the magazine. Can an error?

Comment: Not necessarily wrong.  It just seems weird to have the extraneous factor of $2$.

Comment: @lulu: Let $a=...=d=3^{1/3}.$ Then $A<0$

Comment: Which contradicts your claim...so, again, are you sure you have written down what you meant to?

Comment: I think it's a error in my magazine

Comment: You inequality is true with the following condition. $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{a^3+1}=2.$ If you want I am ready to post a solution.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg: Thank you very much.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg: I edited!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the condition $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{a^3+1}=2$ it's true:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1-a}{1-a+a^2}=\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{1-a}{1-a+a^2}+\frac{4}{3}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{a^3+1}\right)\right)=\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a-1)^2(2a+1)}{3(a^3+1)}\geq0.$$

Answer (score 3):

Since
$$
\sum_{k=1}^4\frac1{1+a_k^3}=2
$$
we have
$$
\sum_{k=1}^4\frac{a_k^3}{1+a_k^3}=2
$$
By [Holder's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality), with $p=\frac32$ and $q=3$,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^4\frac{a_k^2\cdot1}{1+a_k^3}
&\le\left(\sum_{k=1}^4\frac{a_k^3}{1+a_k^3}\right)^{2/3}\left(\sum_{k=1}^4\frac1{1+a_k^3}\right)^{1/3}\\
&=2
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^4\frac{1-a_k}{1-a_k+a_k^2}
&=\sum_{k=1}^4\frac{1-a_k^2}{1+a_k^3}\\
&\ge2-2\\[9pt]
&=0
\end{align}
$$